# "System.FormatException: Only integer can be converted" when creating X509Certificate2 object from .pfx file

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate2

I am trying to add a pfx certificate from c# using the X509Certificate2 constructor. The certificate was creating using these two commands from OpenSSL:

`req -x509 -sha256 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout keyname.key -out certificatename.crt -days 365`
and
`pkcs12 -export -in C:\path\to\certificatename.crt -inkey C:\path\to\keyname.key -out C:\path\to\newpkcs12.pfx`

My C# code looks like this

```
X509Store store = new X509Store("TestStore", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
string certPath = /Certificate/" + "mycertificate.pfx";

X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certPath, "12345678");
```

The line with the X509Certificate2 constructor throws the error `S"System.FormatException: Only integer can be converted\r\n  at Mono.Security.ASN1Convert.ToInt32 (Mono.Security.ASN1 asn1) [0x00017] in <ca59a709f9e24fa0adef388a18d30264>:0 \r\n  at Mono.Security.X509.PKCS12.Decrypt (Mono.Security.PKCS7+EncryptedData ed) [0x00033] in <ca59a709f9e24fa0adef388a18d30264>:0 \r\n  at Mono.Security.X509.PKCS12.Decode (System.Byte[] data) [0x00271] in <ca59a709f9e24fa0adef388a18d30264>:0 \r\n  at Mono.Security.X509.PKCS12..ctor (System.Byte[] data, System.String password) [0x0000d] in <ca59a709f9e24fa0adef388a18d30264>:0 \r\n  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2ImplMono.ImportPkcs12 (System.Byte[] rawData, System.String password) [0x00023] in <d054a9182977441aa432503a474315ba>:0 \r\n  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2ImplMono.ImportPkcs12 (System.Byte[] rawData, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password) [0x0001b] in <d054a9182977441aa432503a474315ba>:0 \r\n  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2ImplMono..ctor (System.Byte[] rawData, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x0002f] in <d054a9182977441aa432503a474315ba>:0 \r\n  at Mono.X509PalImpl.ImportFallback (System.Byte[] data, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00000] in <d054a9182977441aa432503a474315ba>:0 \r\n  at Mono.X509PalImplMono.Import (System.Byte[] data, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00000] in <d054a9182977441aa432503a474315ba>:0 \r\n  at Mono.SystemCertificateProvider.Import (System.Byte[] data, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags, Mono.CertificateImportFlags importFlags) [0x00017] in <d054a9182977441aa432503a474315ba>:0 \r\n  at Mono.SystemCertificateProvider.Mono.ISystemCertificateProvider.Import (System.Byte[] data, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags, Mono.CertificateImportFlags importFlags) [0x00000] in <d054a9182977441aa432503a474315ba>:0 \r\n  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Helper.Import (System.Byte[] rawData, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00005] in <787acc3c9a4c471ba7d971300105af24>:0 \r\n  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor (System.String fileName, System.String password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x0003e] in <787acc3c9a4c471ba7d971300105af24>:0 \r\n  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor (System.String fileName, System.String password) [0x00000] in <787acc3c9a4c471ba7d971300105af24>:0 \r\n  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor (System.String fileName, System.String password) [0x00000] in <d054a9182977441aa432503a474315ba>:0`

I am able to verify that my password is correct by installing the certificate with the windows certificate wizard. I am also able to verify that the certificate file is at the supplied path.

I have tried a password with and without numbers.

At this point I am starting to think it is a bug with the windows certificate library as I cannot find a lot of information on this error online.

Comment: Looks to be an issue with one of the ASN encoded values in the PFX. Do you have any idea what encrypion algorithm was used to encrypt the PFX? `openssl asn1parse -inform PEM -in FileNameHere -i` might tell you. It looks like it might be an unsupported encryption, judging from the stack trace.

Comment: @Charlieface that command returns `Error reading PEM file
28450000:error:0480006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:773`

I assume I need to explicitly set the encryption algorithm when I create the PFX. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How are you creating it, it sounds like it might be corrupted? I would expect it would start with `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY` or `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE` or something like that

Comment: @Charlieface I created a console app and had no issues with the certificate. My main app is built with Unity which I guess is where the problem lies. Seems similar to this issue https://forum.unity.com/threads/are-x509certificate2-classes-only-partially-supported-by-unity.1461968/